# Merge and replace table id with name of two table SQL

Tags: php, mysql, join, merge

table customers:

```
+----+------------+
| id | text       |
+----+------------+
| 33 | name1      | 
| 34 | name2      | 
| 35 | name3      | 
| 36 | name4      | 
+----+------------+
```

table orders:

```
+----+--------+------------+----------+
| id |  cid   |  ordername |  colors  |
+----+--------+------------+----------+
|  8 |   34   |    name    |    5     |        
+----+--------+------------+----------+
```

Is possible with one query have this result?

```
+----+--------+------------+----------+
| id |  cid   |  ordername |  colors  |
+----+--------+------------+----------+
|  8 | name1  |    name    |    5     |        
+----+--------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: what is eid ? and cid is not name2 in your result ?

Comment: Using a join and aliases, assuming that `name1` should really be `name2`

Answer (score 3):

here how you can do it

```
   select o.`id`, `text` as cid , `ordername`, `colors` from orders o
   inner join customers c
   on  c.id = o.cid
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/951e8/6)

OUTPUT:

```
   ID   CID     ORDERNAME   COLORS
   8    name2   name              5
```